# Как с помощью регулярных выражений проверить введенные данные в форме?

Tags: javascript, html, регулярные-выражения

Код формы:

```
<form role="form" id="payment-form" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Номер</label>
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Number" placeholder="Номер" required />
<span class="input-group-addon">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="bbankCard" type="button">Принять</button>
```

При этом нельзя менять `<button>` на `<input>`.
Как данные, которые я введу в поле формы, отправить обработчику JS и проверить на совпадение с `var number = new RegExp("/^\d{12,18}$/");` с помощью метода `test()`.

Comment: Вам нужно проверить, что введенное число лежит в некотором диапазоне?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов честно признаться не знаю, видимо да. Мне дали код RegEx и метод.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример. При не подходящем значении подсвечивается поле (розовым фоном, для примера). Возможно, потребуется добавить сообщение, чтобы было понятно что не верно. При вводе или копировании в поле подсветка ошибки сбрасывается. Заменил тип кнопки (было button, поставил submit) чтобы отправлять форму. Удалил куски  html разметки, чтобы не загромождать.

```js
var regex = /^\d{12,18}$/;

$('#payment-form').on('submit', function(e) {
  var ctNumber = $(this).find('input[name="Number"]');
  var currentVal = $(ctNumber).val();

  if (!regex.test(currentVal)) {
    $(ctNumber).addClass('invalid');
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  // тут добавить текст ошибки или вызвать другое событие или еще что-то
  e.preventDefault(); // это убрать
});

$('#payment-form input[name="Number"]').on('input', function(e) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('invalid'))
    $(this).removeClass('invalid')
});
```

```css
.invalid {
  background-color: #ffb9e1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="payment-form">
  <label>Номер</label>
  <input type="text" name="Number" placeholder="Номер" required />
  <button type="submit">Принять</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

$("#bbankCard").click(function test(){
var whatinput;

var number = new RegExp("/^\d{12,18}$/");

whatinput= $("input.form-control").val();

if () //здесь идет сравнение методом тест whatinput и number;
}
);

jquerry Должно быть подключено.
либо подключаете этот скрипт в конце либо используете ready()

Comment: дописал полностью .(помучался с регэкспом, так как он отказывался воспринимать выражение в ковычках) $("#bbankCard").click(function test(){
var whatinput;
var number = new RegExp(/^\d{12,18}$/);
whatinput=$("input.form-control").val();
alert(number);
if(number.test(whatinput)){
 alert("its number");
}
else{alert("error");}
}
);
вместо алертов подставляете свои обработчики